# MongoDB: query value using varied key, in an object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I had a tough time when tried to retrieve field value using varied key, in an object, for example:

Running command:

```
db.stuff.find()
```

will give:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5963e65f948dc563d6375f7b"),
   "color_map":{  
      "APPLE":"red",
      "BANANA":"yellow",
      "SKY":"blue"
   },
   "type":"APPLE"
}
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5963e65f948dc563d6375f77"),
   "color_map":{  
      "BANANA":"yellow",
      "PEACH":"pink",
      "SKY":"blue"
   },
   "type":"PEACH"
}
```

So the question is, how to get the color results using pure MongoDB operators (will prefer using aggregate operators), to get the following result:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5963e65f948dc563d6375f7b"),
   "type":"APPLE",
   "color":"red"
}
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5963e65f948dc563d6375f77"),
   "type":"PEACH",
   "color":"pink"
}
```

Follow-up: The mongoDB version is 3.2.9, and upgrading to latest version will cause other components to crash, so could we implement it without using $objectToArray (new in 3.4.4)?

Comment: Seems like kind of an odd way to store this info.  Are you sure this is the best way for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$objectToArray` to convert `color_map` embedded doc into array of key value ( `k v` ) pairs in `3.4.4` version.

`$indexOfArray`operator to find the matching `type's` index in `color_map` followed by `$arrayElemAt` to retrieve the element at found index and projecting the value of element into `color` field.

`$let` to create the `colorkvs` variable and reference inside `in` expression.

Something like below

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
    {
      "$project": {
        "color": {
          "$let": {
            "vars": {
              "colorkvs": {
                "$objectToArray": "$color_map"
              }
            },
            "in": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {
                  "colorkv": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$colorkvs",
                      {
                        "$indexOfArray": [
                          "$$colorkvs.k",
                          "$type"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "in": "$$colorkv.v"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "type":1
      }
    }
])
```

You can shorten the pipeline by removing the outer `$let` expression.

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "color": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "colorkv": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                  "$objectToArray": "$color_map"
                },
                {
                  "$indexOfArray": [
                    {
                      "$objectToArray": "$color_map"
                    },
                    "$type"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": "$$colorkv.v"
        }
      },
      "type": 1
    }
  }
])
```

JS solution for lower versions

```
db.collectionname.find({}).map( doc => ({
     "_id": doc._id,
     "type": doc.type,
     "color": doc.color_map[Object.keys(doc.color_map).find(k => k === doc.type)]
}));
```